# replacing something else after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this html:

```
<a href="#" class="cancel" id="cancel_3'">cancel</a>
```

when the user clicks cancel, i want to remove the hyperlink and i want to replace this with an image i.e.

```
$.ajax({
        context:this,
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions/cancel.php",
        data: "id=" + the_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {

            $(this).remove;
         // add image
```

thanks :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
success: function() {
  $( "a#cancel_3" ).replaceWith( "<img...>" );
}
```

You'll have to fill in the HTML in the replaceWith function with whatever you want to replace the link with.   is just a placeholder I used.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(this).css('display', 'none').after('<img>');
```